# Differentiability of $\tan^2(g(x,y))/g(x,y)$ at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

A student I'm helping came to me with this exercise on differentiability of a multivariable function. (I'm told it was part of a practice exam in analysis, but I don't know the exact source.)

> Let $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable, with $g(x,y)=0$ at the origin and $g(x,y)\neq0$ otherwise. Consider the function
>
> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{\tan^2(g(x,y))}{g(x,y)}&\text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
>
> a) Calculate the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $g$.
>
> b) Show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I do not plan on sharing the entire solution with the student at once, only doling out hints to push them in the right direction - provided the solution is correct, of course!

---

**Attempt for part (a)**

Using the definition for partial derivative and properties of limits, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}h \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\tan^2(g(h,0))}{h\cdot g(h,0)} \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin^2(g(h,0))}{g(h,0)^2} \cdot \frac{g(h,0))}{h\cos^2(g(h,0))} \\[1ex]
&= \underbrace{\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(g(h,0))}{g(h,0)}\right)^2}_{\to1} \cdot \underbrace{\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{\cos^2(g(h,0))}}_{\to1} \cdot \lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(h,0)}h \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(0+h,0)-g(0,0)}h \\[1ex]
&= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,0)
\end{align}$$

and I use the same argument to claim $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(0,0)$. Given the language of the question, I'm led to believe there's no way to determine the precise value of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,0)$.

---

**Attempt for part (b)**

If I'm not misremembering, to establish that $f$ is differentiable at a point, I need to show that $f$ is continuous at, and differentiable in a neighborhood around, that point.

Continuity at the origin: I claim that $f$ is bounded near the origin,

$$\left|\frac{\tan^2(g(x,y))}{g(x,y)}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(g(x,y))}{g(x,y)}\right|^2 \cdot \left|\frac{g(x,y)}{\cos^2(g(x,y))}\right| \le \frac{|g(x,y)|}{\cos^2(g(x,y))}
\stackrel{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\to 0$$

using that $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ for all $x$.

Differentiability around the origin: Borrowing the previous inequality,

$$\left|\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| = \left|\frac{\tan^2(g(x,y))}{g(x,y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \le \frac{|g(x,y)|}{\cos^2(g(x,y))\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

which I believe also approaches $0$, since $g$ is differentiable. According to [definition 1](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiability-multivariable-real-functions-part1/) this means

$$\left|\frac{g(x,y)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| = \frac{|g(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \stackrel{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\to 0$$

---

Are these arguments valid? If not, what needs to be corrected/elaborated? Where can I improve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Taylor's Theorem for the $\tan (x)$ function, to write
\begin{equation}
\tan x =x +\mathcal{O}(x^3)\implies \tan^2 (x)= x^2 +\mathcal{O}(x^4)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{x}$ is a smooth function in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Then, note that
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\tan^2(g(x,y))}{g(x,y)}= \frac{g^2(x,y)+\mathcal{O}(g^4(x,y))}{g(x,y)}=g(x,y)+\mathcal{O}(g^3(x,y))
\end{equation}
where of course $\mathcal{O}(g(x,y))$ is a differentiable function from composition of smooth with differentiable.

We immediately obtain the result.